# Catching child's post_save on parent

Tags: python, django

There is a parent class with post_create catcher:

```
class ParentClass(SomeParentModel):
  # parent's code

@receiver(post_save, sender=ParentClass):
  # some code after catching the signal
```

And there is a child class:

```
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
  # child's code
```

For some reason `post_save` never get triggered when initializing `ChildClass`. What is done wrong here?

Edit: may be one have to implement `post_save()` at `ChildNode` and call `super()` ?

Comment: Why not add another receiver on ChildClass? Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: I kind of think it feels right for not being called in childclass. I think you need to implement it in childclass agian, or call super maybe

Comment: I lean towards your opinion. Have to implement post_save inside each of the child classes separately.